# Firefox SDK Addon - Context menu item icon not working

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I tried out the same code as given here - 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Add_a_Context_Menu_Item#Adding_an_image

on Firefox v38.0 using jpm v1.0.

But it does not work. I am pretty sure I did not mess up my image path or size. I used a 16x16 png image.

Does this work for anyone ?